# SqlCommandBuilder using table name instead of view

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlcommandbuilder

I am using a SqlCommandBuilder object to generate update statements from Select statements in a SqlDataAdapter.

My problem is that in my Select statement I am selecting from a view called vwUsers. the SqlCommandBuilder object I used generated an update statement for the table Users not the view vwUsers. How can I override that behavior ?

(I need it to use the view because this is where the triggers are being executed. We added triggers to the table view instead of the original table)

Comment: didn't know it was that hard!

Comment: 7 years later I have the same problem !! http://stackoverflow.com/q/30749222/2504785

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by dropping the command builder and writing the SQL update command myself !

Comment: Finally, I did the same like you! ;)