# SqlCommandBuilder() creates insert/update for underlying tables instead for a view

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

I have two schemas, like this:

- Schema 'data' --> holds tables, and nobody has access to them from outside
- Schema 'ui' --> holds views which are accessibly from outside; the idea is that you can select/delete/update/insert on these views. Thus, I am doing **ownership  chaining.**

For example:

```
create table data.tblTest (TestKey int not null primary key);
create view ui.vwTest as select * from data.tblTest;
```

Now, if I connect as a user with SQL Studio, everything is OK:

```
select * from ui.vwTest; -- WORKS (this is correct)
select * from data.tblTest; -- ERROR (this is correct)

insert into   ui.vwTest  (TestKey) values (17); -- WORKS (this is correct)
insert into data.tblTest (TestKey) values (17); -- ERROR (this is correct)
```

However, if I write a program in .NET/C# which uses SqlCommandBuilder:

```
SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter('select * from ui.vwTest', conn);
SqlCommandBuilder b = new SqlCommandBuilder(mSQLAda);
ada.UpdateCommand = b.GetUpdateCommand();
ada.InsertCommand = b.GetInsertCommand();
ada.DeleteCommand = b.GetDeleteCommand();
```

==> Then in the following, the **INSERT DOES NOT WORK**!

**[EDIT]:**

The SqlCommandBuilder is analyzing the View, and instead of creating a command like

```
INSERT INTO ui.vwTest ...
```

it is creating

```
INSERT INTO data.tblTest ...
```

So in fact, the SqlCommandBuilder tries to be "intelligent" and accesses the underlying tables of the view, instead of accessing the view.

**Question: Can this behaviour be changed ?**

BTW, just to make it more clear, I am doing **ownership chaining** here.

My users have the right to see the views in schema **ui**, but they no rights to schema **data**. However, due to ownership chaning, the users can access the tables indirectly via the views in schema **data**.

In detail, a user is attached to a custom role, e.g. "role_user", and the role has rights to the schema, as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON SCHEMA ui TO role_user ;
```

but the role has NO RIGHTS on Schema 'data' !!

The nice thing of this setup is that you can apply row-level-security. With a where filter within the view, you can select only records the user is allowed to see.

As said, it works fine within the SQL window, but not with the SQLCommandBuilder. The SQLCommandBuilder analyzes the view, and tries to directly access the underlying tables, instead of accessing the view.

7 years ago, someone asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/320684/2504785
And his solution then was to write the SQL commands himself. 
But possibly, there exists now another solution? However, I found none so far ...

**[/EDIT]**

Comment: I don't think the problem is with `SqlCommandBuilder`.  
Your view is in a different schema then the table, and my guess is that the connection from c# doesn't have access rights to this schema, or to this table.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: In the code You see that, the view was accessed, but in the error message mention about the table. Giosco don't want to give access to the table, just for the view.

Comment: I currently don't have a server to play with, but if memory serves you need to have select rights on all tables that the view is selecting from, However, if you use a stored procedure, you only need execute rights. I'll try to verify that in a few hours.

Comment: Sorry @ZoharPeled, You are right. Giosco see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx#Security

Comment: Or maybe this is the explanation about this situation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: [Read the answers to this question on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368414/grant-select-on-a-view-not-base-table) One of them states a solution that might also work in your case (where the view and the base tables belong to different schema)

Comment: @ZoharPeled No, I am using **ownership chaining**. I edited the question to make it more clear. The user does not need a direct access to the table.

Comment: @GaborRajczi Thank you for posting. Yes, I have set it up like in these documents, and I really believe now that the SQLCommandBuilder tries to be "intelligent" and accesses the underlying tables of the view, but this is wrong. The CommandBuilder should only access the view. I have edited the question also. I will also try to find out more and post it here,  or even I write an article.

Comment: Note this part of the [ownership chaining documentation:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) *"When an object is accessed through a chain, SQL Server first compares the owner of the object to the owner of the calling object. This is the previous link in the chain. **If both objects have the same owner, permissions on the referenced object are not evaluated.**"*

I think you should change the owner of the UI schema to the same owner of the Data schema to make it work.

Comment: Also note [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6383578/3094533) from the SO question I've linked earlier.

Comment: I'm back on this issue. I have now clear evidence that the SqlCommandBuilder really creates an `INSERT`statement for the underlying table, instead of for the view. I edited the question again. So far, it seems that the only solution is to replace the SqlCommandBuilder by writing own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OK, the answer now definitively is:**

The `SqlCommandBuilder` is trying to be "intelligent". If you open it with a command like `SELECT * FROM vwTest`, then it analyzes the view and creates commands for the underlying table, like `INSERT into tblTest` ...

So the **problem** is: `SqlCommandBuilder` creates commands for the underlying table, instead of for the view.

**Solution:**

So far, I found no way to change the behaviour of `SqlCommandBuilder`.

Therefore, I rewrote all the loading and updating, and I am doing now everything manually. Loading now takes place purely with `SqlDataReader` -- without loading into a `DataTable` with `SqlDataAdapter`. And all updating is done via creating and executing  `SqlCommand`, without `SqlCommandBuilder`.

It was a lot of work, but as a reward, the application is now **blazing fast**. Loading is **far** faster than with the `SqlCommandBuilder` and `SqlDataAdapter`. Possibly I will make a benchmark comparison at some time. But when a load took 5 seconds before, it is now done "immediatedly".

Answer (score 0):

Note this part of the [ownership chaining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx) documentation:

> When an object is accessed through a chain, SQL Server first compares the owner of the object to the owner of the calling object. This is the previous link in the chain. **If both objects have the same owner**, permissions on the referenced object are **not evaluated**."

Therefor, in order for the ownership chaining to work properly, your table and view must be **owned** by the same principle.

You can change the view's owner or the table's owner by executing an [`ALTER AUTHORIZATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx) sql statement on the object.
Note that this statement only change the owner, not the schema the object belongs to. 
In your case, I would recommend changing the owner of the `UI` schema to the same owner of the `Data` schema, while keeping the permissions of the database principle that uses the `UI` schema intact.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::UI TO <owner_of_the_data_schema>;
```

Note: `<owner_of_the_data_schema>` is a placeholder I've used since I don't know the owner name.

This way, your application user still only have access to whatever is in the `ui` schema, but the ownership chaining allows the objects in the `ui` schema to interact with the objects in the `data` schema.

Comment: Of course, this answer only works if the owner of the table and the view are in fact different. The OP's "`insert into   ui.vwTest  (TestKey) values (17); -- WORKS (this is correct)`" suggests to me that this part is set up correctly already.

Comment: @hvd Note that this part works when the OP is executing this statement from SSMS, meaning that he is probably logged in as a different database user then the one he is using in his c# application...

Comment: Perhaps (I'm not convinced -- why would a login from SSMS use a different user?), but either way, still not a user that has permission to insert into the table: that fails even from SSMS, according to the question.

Comment: most of the time in all the places I've worked in, developers are connecting to SSMS using sa (or some other high-permissions principles). I believe that this is the case here also. If you are connected as sa, there is no meaning to the failure of the ownership chaining, since sa obviously has all the permissions needed...

Comment: Yeah, but sa would typically have permissions to insert data into the raw table, too, and the user the OP is actually using doesn't. At any rate, right now, we're both pretty much making guesses. Educated guesses, but guesses nonetheless. The OP can surely comment whether your answer works.

Comment: It is pretty sure a problem with SQLCommandBuilder. On the server side, I have checked everything. In SSMS, for testing, I'm connecting of course as "end user", not as "sa". The SQLCommandBuilder tries to be "intelligent" and creates a SQL statement that directly inserts into the underlying table, instead of using the view. I'm currently working on that and will later on post here or write an article. It is a very misleading issue! I've found some similar issues in the net, where people were suspecting the database, while in fact the SQLCommandBuilder seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: @SQLPolice will be looking forward for the conclusions. If you do decide to post an article, please leave a link in the comments so that I can read it. thanks.